# Why float type can store 0x0123?

Tags: java, data-structures

I see someone assign `float f = 0x0123` in Java code, and the code can compile and run without error.

How can we call this kind of behavior when assigning 'special' value in float?
And why float can hold it? Thanks.

Comment: What to you mean by 'special'? It's just the hexadecimal representation of a normal number.

Comment: 0x0123 is just hexadecimal notation for 291, so it is no different than `float f = 291;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x0123` is hexadecimal, it means number 291 in decimal, so you can assign it to a `float`. See jls about [HexNumeral](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-HexNumeral):

> HexDigit: (one of)  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F
>
> HexNumeral: 0 x HexDigits